# Number formatting Issue between .rpt file and .pdf file

Tags: vb.net, pdf, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am trying to export the crystal report from vb.net code in xx.rpt and xx.pdf file formats.
There were some calculations in the report. In a particular formula field, when I do a multiplication(say 76.38 * 1.08420006), in pdf file the output is correct with 82.81. But in .rpt file it was 8.288.112.418.28 having all decimal places in wrong position.

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: you should be able to format the object and limit it to 2 places. either in the formula or from the gui

Comment: I am generating .rpt file and .pdf file from same button click with same input and different file formats. But the outputs are different as i mentioned above.